# Quiero saber cuál es el hotel más popular en cuanto a la cantidad de órdenes que hubo

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
select x.id_hotel as id,

x.nazvanie as hotel,

x.mesto as place,count(m.num_room) as orders

from hotels x,room b, zakaz m 

where b.id_hotel=x.id_hotel and b.id_room=m.num_room

group by m.num_room,x.nazvanie,x.id_hotel,x.mesto

order by m.num_room asc
```

Comment: Procura siempre añadir a tus preguntas de BD, la definición de las tablas sobre las que corres la consulta y algunos datos de prueba para entender qué quieres obtener. Ahora mismo nos muestras una consulta (eso está bien), pero no sabemos que problema tiene la consulta o cuál es tu pregunta.

Comment: Lo otro, mysql o sql server?

Comment: Votaré negativamente la pregunta porque, literalmente, hay cientos de miles de resultados en google acerca de la utilización del order by. Al responder este tipo de preguntas le estamos quitando al usuario la oportunidad de investigar y aprender por sí mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta Ordenandolo de la Siguiente Manera.

```
ORDER BY orders DESC
```

Comment: Puedes agregar más detalles de cómo ayudaría tu respuesta a la pregunta?